# Making axis title in Excel chart with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I create an excel chart with VBA and then format the axis titles and fonts' size. The following code works well for the Horizontal axis

```
cht.SetElement msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis
cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Factor of Safety"
cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 15
```

However, the similar code for the Vertical axis

```
cht.SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Depth [mCD]"
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 15
```

leads to the error 424 "Object required". Could you please tell me what happened ?

Comment: Can you post the full code? You might have destroyed `cht` object by the time you get to vertical axis. Can you check if `cht` is still an object by the time you get to it?

Comment: @Zac: actually those two pieces of code go together and there is no code in between, that's why i can not understand and post a question here. Of course i did not make that apparent mistake.
Preceding of those two part is a standard code to initiate a chart.

Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=240,XlChartType:=xlXYScatter,Left:=Cells(2, 9).Left,Top:=Cells(2, 9).Top,Width:=350,Height:=500).Chart

Comment: Could you try and destroy `cht` object and reset it before attempting to set `msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent versions of Excel, you can use `SetElement` with a named constant to add features to the chart. This *seems* easier, but it's less intuitive in terms of what it actually does, and it can be unreliable.

So instead of this:

```
cht.SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Depth [mCD]"
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 15
```

do this:

```
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Depth [mCD]"
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer expanding off of Jon Peltier's answer:

```
Charts.Add
With ActiveChart        
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True ' must set outside with       
    With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)      
        .AxisTitle.Text = "Depth [mCD]"
        .AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 15       
    End With        
End With
```

Comment: `.HasTitle` can be set within the same `With` block as the other statements.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Office 16 and noticed that the code would appear to work if ".text" is changed to ".caption".

```
Sub AddAxisTitles()

'apply caption to abscissa
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Caption = "Connector Pitch (in.)"

'apply caption to ordinate axis
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption = "Station"

End Sub
```