# How to generate a graph with axis titles without getting a runtime 424 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to generate graphs and used the macro recorder to do it.  When it gets to the part where I put the axis titales in it runs a "runtime error 424 object required" error.  What am i missing?

I wrote this macro once and it only put in one of the axis titles.  When i tried to add the second one in i kept getting errors and gave up and decided to re-record it.  Now i can't get either one on my graph.

```
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "# Samples"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "# Samples"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 
    9).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
```

Comment: See https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/979449-adding-axis-titles-using-vba.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645054/making-axis-title-in-excel-chart-with-vba

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions TIm,  I gave both a try and for the first one i got another run-time error, this time 438, object does not support this property or method.  The second suggestion gives me the same 424.

Comment: Well those codes do work, so there seems to be something else that's the problem.